# Add User as owner of Azure AD Group through REST API

Tags: azure-rest-api, azure-ad-b2b

Is it possible to add the owner to the Azure AD group from any REST API?

I think I should have one service principal and I have to generate an access token to do that.

I tried to generate access token and used below query to add owner via Postman.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupid/owners/$ref
```

But I am facing `403 Forbidden` error like below:

> { "error": { "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied", "message":
> "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.", "innerError": {
> "date": "2022-06-29T05:42:38", "request-id":
> "ebd01257-b890-4b3d-8c22-a1b34738e5a6", "client-request-id":
> "ebd01257-b890-4b3d-8c22-a1b34738e5a6" } }

I have granted API permissions like below:

[image]

What else permissions are needed? Is there any other way instead of Postman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can make use of [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) instead of Postman that doesn't require you to generate access token separately.***

You can call the same query by granting below `permissions` based on your account type:

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and added the owner to the Azure AD group like below:***

After running the above query, owner added successfully like below:

[image]

***To confirm the above, check the portal whether the **`owner`** is added or not like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Add owners - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)